# Kotlin coroutine Job's join method

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have found very strange documentation for join method:

> In particular, it means that a parent coroutine invoking join on a
> child coroutine that was started using launch(coroutineContext) { ...
> } builder throws CancellationException if the child had crashed,
> unless a non-standard CoroutineExceptionHandler is installed in the
> context.

I'm not sure that CoroutineExceptionHandler will have effect for CancellationException.
Example:

```
fun main() = runBlocking {
    val handler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, exception ->
        println("CoroutineExceptionHandler got $exception")
    }
    val job = GlobalScope.launch(handler) {
        val inner = launch { // all this stack of coroutines will get cancelled
            throw IOException() // the original exception
        }
        try {
            inner.join()
        } catch (e: CancellationException) {
            println("handle join")
        }
    }
    job.join()
}
```

Output:

```
handle 
join CoroutineExceptionHandler got java.io.IOException
```

So basically CancellationException will still be thrown regardless any installed handlers.
Am I right?

Comment: Yes, I believe the doc is wrong. The coroutine exception handler is ignored everywhere except in a top-level coroutine context (one whose `Job` element has no parent).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Your innerJob will still throw a `CancellationException`, and in your outer job you'll get a crash, since you don't handle the `exception`.

See: https://pl.kotl.in/1Uqw8nmNS

Comment: So the documentation statement is incorrect, right?